# Update your app to support OAuth 2.0 before 12/13/1

Tags: oauth, facebook

I am using the following java script api for facebook connect http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php

Then i received this email from fb

> Dear Developer,
>
> As part of our continued efforts to migrate all apps to OAuth 2.0, we opted in all apps using the new JavaScript SDK to OAuth 2.0 this afternoon at 11am PT and reverted at 1:30pm because we noticed that your app has not migrated. Please ensure that you have set the oauth param in FB.init to true and that you are using FB.getAuthResponse to obtain the access token.
>
> Read more in the OAuth2 migration announcement, updates to the new JS SDK blog post, or our JS SDK docs.

But i did't updated my fb connect implementation and it is still working fine. I am not sure will this effect my fb connect in future? and secondly why my implementation is still working fine? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it will stop working very soon. You should migrate to the new version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the new version as soon as possible.  I've been dealing with Facebook and their various APIs for four years now.  This is the most warning they've ever given for deprecating anything, so this is big for them.  Upgrade your websites ASAP.  :)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for helping me on this. I really appreciate it.